# Как "присвоить" функцию в переменную?

Tags: c#, функции

Здравствуйте как "присвоить" функцию в переменную:

Есть мат. функции: `int sum(a,b); int sub(a,b); int div(a,b)`

Есть код:

```
void main(){
   operation = sum;
}

var operation;
int calc(a,b)
{
   ...
   operation(a,b);
   ...
}
```

P.S. Я знаю, как передать функцию в виде аргумента, но тут другая ситуация и нужно именно функцию "присвоить" переменной.

Comment: Вам знакомо понятие делегата?

Comment: Вообще про делегаты нужно знать. А так [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549151.aspx) для функций возвращающих значение и [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/018hxwa8.aspx) для функций без возвращаемого значения.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас почитаю

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы присвоить функцию переменной, нужно чтобы переменная имела тип делегата, который описывает в точности такую же сигнатуру функции.

Вот пример с двумя вариантами:

```
class Program
{
    //Можно явно создать делегат, описывающий нужную сигнатуру
    delegate int MathOperation(int a, int b);
    //И использовать его как тип
    static MathOperation Operation1;

    //Либо не создавать явно делегат, а использовать Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>
    static Func<int, int, int> Operation2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Operation1 = Sub;
        var sub = Operation1(10, 5);

        Operation2 = Sum;
        var sum = Operation2(10, 5);
    }

    static int Sub(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    static int Sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```